# How do I make dynamic dependant excel VBA comboboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have three Combo Boxes. 
One for state, one for district and one for city.

So far I have managed to populate my first combobox with a list of unique state names.

I need a sub to run when a state is picked in the first combobox which picks the corresponding  districts and selects the first one(by default), and similarly the first city is selected in the third combobox corresponding to the first district (by default).

I need a sub to run when a district is picked in the second combobox which picks the corresponding  cities and selects the first one(by default).

Then the user should be able to pick a city and view data related to that city.

How do I make these sub routines?

Note:

`"States"` is my list of states, with repitions.

`"uniqueStates"` is the name of the first Combobox.

`"districList"` is the name of the second combobox.
`"cityList"` is the name of the third combobox.

```
Function UniqueList()
  'Populate control with


  'unique list.


  Range("States").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
  CopyToRange:=Range("uniqueStates"), Unique:=True


  'Set combo control's Row Source property.


  Range("uniqueStates").Activate


  UserForm1.uniqueStateList.RowSource = Selection.CurrentRegion.Address


  'Display user form.


  UserForm1.Show


  Selection.CurrentRegion.Clear


End Function
```

Also I can't figure out why the first comboBox is populated with the first State name twice. The rest of the entries are unique, just the first is a duplicate.

Comment: How does your data look like? If you have data in an excel-table, how this table looks like? Could you add a sample of the data you are using?

Answer (score 0):

it's a Bug. If you try to make directly by Excel, the bug remain...
Add:

```
Range("uniqueStates").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

By-pass the bug...